# Palantir Foundry REST API call for adding a row identifier to a dataset

Tags: python, rest, palantir-foundry, apache-arrow

I am currently using the `Read dataset as table` Palantir Foundry API as described [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/api/datasets-resources/datasets/read-table/). For datasets of a certain size, I end up running into memory constraints when pulling the data using this API call (I'm using `Arrow`, not `CSV`. As a workaround, I've broken up my dataset into subsets using the `columns` parameter, which allows me to specify a list of columns. My intention is to merge the `Arrow` output into a single table, like as follows:

```
merged_table = pa.concat_tables([table1, table2])
```

However, the `Read dataset as table` API's row order is non-deterministic, so I can't simply apply the above code to the table subsets. As a preliminary step, it seems as though I would need to add a row identifier to the Foundry dataset. I can of course do this using a code repository within the Foundry web interface, but I would much rather have this done entirely through API calls. Is there a way that I can programmatically add a row identifier through a Foundry API call? I've looked through the documentation, and can't seem to find anything about doing any kind of data transformation through API calls.

The Below example generates an Apache Arrow table from a Palantir Foundry dataset.

```
def foundry_arrow_exporter(
    dataset_rid,
    token,
    base_url,
    column_list=None):
    
    headers = {
    "authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token)
    }

    # Warning: This endpoint is in preview and may be modified or removed at any time. 
    # To use this endpoint, add preview=true to the request query parameters. 
    # Furthermore, this endpoint currently does not support views (Virtual datasets composed of other datasets).
    if column_list:
        columns = ','.join(column_list)
        response = requests.get(f'{base_url}/api/v1/datasets/{dataset_rid}/readTable?format=ARROW&columns={columns}&preview=True', headers=headers)
    else:
        response = requests.get(f'{base_url}/api/v1/datasets/{dataset_rid}/readTable?format=ARROW&preview=True', headers=headers)

    response.raise_for_status()
    buffer = pa.py_buffer(response.content)
    table = pa.ipc.open_stream(buffer).read_all()
    return table

arrow_table = foundry_arrow_exporter(
    dataset_rid=dataset_rid,
    token=foundry_token, 
    base_url=foundry_base_url,
    column_list = column_chunk)
```

Comment: Are you able to stream the data to disk to avoid memory issues?

e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests

Comment: Why don't you download the underlying Parquet files, this would avoid the memory pressure? Have a look at Foundry DevTools how to do that.

Comment: @user5233494 - from what I recall when I tried implementing your approach maybe a couple months back, applying `readTable?format=CSV` instead of `readTable?format=ARROW` and streaming it to disk was far slower, so I didn't go with that approach. I'll revisit to confirm.

Comment: @nicornk - good suggestion, I'll give that a look.